How to run typescript code in dotnet backend
The UI is built on typescript and the business wants to run a particular logic (legacy code) in the backend when a trigger occurs. As the UI code is tightly coupled, replicating it in the backend or making any changes to that code could lead to millions of losses if any error occurs or any logic fails/misses.
How do I run the typescript code in the .Net 8 API backend?
I've tried following Stackoverflow suggestion, but Jint and IronJS didn't work for me.
PS:

The .tsx code resides in a shared component.
Why? You may ask: Earlier the entire code was written in react with no backend for PoC, now as the application is in production and scaling up, such requirements have come in.


There might be some ideas in here for you.

"but Jint and IronJS didn't work for me" Why not? What specifically didn't work for you?

Are you attemtping to run the TypeScript code directly or are you transpiling to JavaScript first?

@phuzi, as described in the statement above, I want to run a certain part of the react code in .net and unfortunate part is that the TSX transpiles to JS which then gets minified or min-js and then gets bundled. So, I see a lot of roadblocks before I solve my basic question, like do I need to unbundle first and then decompile the file etc or what?

It sounds like you're going to have a job on your hands to refactor the existing code before you're in a position to attempt what you're asking here. It may be easier to port the existing code to the backend and replace it in the FE with an API call. Without nowing the specifics, this is a call that you will have to make.

You shouldn't have to unpack the JavaScript, you could always run a second task to transpile just the module you need for the backend.

@phuzi, After sorting out the above minor issues, I tried executing the JS file using 4 engines in .net: Jint, ClearScript, IronJS and ChakraCore and it seems like none of the engines listed above support "export" keyword and let's assume I/my-dotnet-code won't have control to edit the JS script so I can't edit the JS code. Any resolutions on this? TIA.

I'm surprised by that as export has been widely supported by browsers since 2017 (Firefox was 2018) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#browser_compatibility

export was added to Version 6 of the EcmaScript standard (ES2015). The IronJS project was last updated 13 years ago, no surprise it didn't work there. If I were you, I would consider running with ClearScript.V8 and ask another question with a [mvce] including a representative example of what you're trying to do.

You can try ClearScript.Here is an example:
using System;
using Microsoft.ClearScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.JavaScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;

using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
{
    engine.AddHostType("Console", typeof(Console));
    engine.Execute("Console.WriteLine('{0} is an interesting number.', Math.PI)");

}

The above will print:
3.14159265358979 is an interesting number.


I went through the documentation and it looks like we can write JS inside .net and run it. But what I'm looking for is pre-written JS code to be executed using some tool. Rewriting TS/JS code is strictly prohibited by the biz team. Any idea whether this ClearScript tool can do that, I don't wanna invest so much time on a tool and later find out that it's futile to my scenario.

Hi @Remo, I was trying to execute the JS file directly using engine.ExecuteDocument command but it threw an error saying: "The script engine is not configured for loading documents". Any idea how to fix this issue as none of the ChatGpt prompt seems to work for this!

Found the solution after beating around the bush. Attaching engine.DocumentSettings = new DocumentSettings() {AccessFlags = DocumentAccessFlags.EnableFileLoading}; solved the issue.

If you have problems because your code is multiple files or because it uses modern JS. One option could be to isolate your modules into one standalone library and then compile it into a single JS file. If you can also use a transpiler like Babel if you need to replace modern JS features. In the end, you should have created a single file that should be more compatible with embedded JS engines.


It seems ClearScript does not support a lot of ECMA6 features like export and other keywords. And let's say I do not have access to the JS file so modifying the TS/JS file is not a feasible solution. 2. Adding "Install Babel" cmd to CI/CD introduces complexities and sometimes the tsc command throws error during runtime.

